# Multiple variables in with_items made error

Tags: ansible, yaml

I created the following playbook to set ufw settings.

```yaml
---
- name: setup ufw for multi ports
  hosts: db
  become: yes

  tasks:
  - name: 'Allow all access for multi ports'
    community.general.ufw:
            rule: allow
            port: "{{ item.port_num }}"
            src: "{{ item.dest_ip }}"
    with_items:
            - { port_num: "33787", dest_ip: "{{web_ip_band}}" }
```

And this is my `group_vars` file.

```yaml
web_ip_band:
  - '192.168.101.13/24'
  - '192.168.101.44/24'
```

when I execute this playbook, I get this error.

> failed: [dbserver01] (item={'port_num': '33787', 'dest_ip': ['192.168.101.13/24', '192.168.101.44/24']}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "commands": ["/usr/sbin/ufw status verbose", "/bin/grep -h '^### tuple' /lib/ufw/user.rules /lib/ufw/user6.rules /etc/ufw/user.rules /etc/ufw/user6.rules /var/lib/ufw/user.rules /var/lib/ufw/user6.rules", "/usr/sbin/ufw --version", "/usr/sbin/ufw allow from ['192.168.101.13/24', '192.168.101.44/24'] to any port 33787"], "item": {"dest_ip": ["192.168.101.13/24", "192.168.101.44/24"], "port_num": "33787"}, "msg": "ERROR: Wrong number of arguments\n"}

Is there a syntax error in my playbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`community.general.ufw` module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ufw_module.html#parameter-from_ip) (extract rearranged to fit in SO answer)

> from_ip (*aliases: from, src*)
>
> **string** - Default: "any"

You are passing a **list** of IPs, which explains your error message:

> ERROR: Wrong number of arguments

You have to play that task for each combination of `port_num` and individual entries in `dest_ip`. What you need here is a [subelements loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements):

```yaml
 - name: 'Allow all access for multi ports'
   community.general.ufw:
     rule: allow
     port: "{{ item.0.port_num }}"
     src: "{{ item.1 }}"
    vars:
      my_rules:
        - { port_num: "33787", dest_ip: "{{web_ip_band}}" }
    loop: "{{ my_rules | subelements('dest_ip') }}"
```